# Two forms on the same level are submitted in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react app with with complex component layout with multiple forms.
I know that placing one form inside another is not allowed. But I have a component which renders a form and must be placed inside my form. To prevent forms be rendered one inside another I use react portal.

But when I try to submit form rendered with portal, first form is also submitted that is unexpected. Looks like I miss something important.

How to prevent first form submit when submitting the second?

Thank you

Simplified example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-boyd-bbv5mo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const Portal = ({ children, elm }) => createPortal(children, elm);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("submit 1");
        }}
      >
        First form <input type="text" value="1" />
        <Portal elm={document.querySelector("body")}>
          Second form{" "}
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              alert("submit 2");
            }}
          >
            <input type="text" value="2" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit 2" />
          </form>
        </Portal>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: try this on your callback function````e.stopPropagation()````

Comment: @EisaRezaei thank you. It works fine. But I don't understand why it is needed if I move second form outside from the inner html of the first one. E.g. I do not need to call stopPropagation here for the third form https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-sun-7xorth?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you should use buttons for submitting the forms inside of forms you can only have one btn with the type of submit, reason of using the ````e.stopPropagation()```` is javascript event handling mode you can find more information about that over here
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-event-bubbling-capturing/#:~:text=Event%20Capturing%20in%20React&text=Actually%20both%20happen%20one%20after,up%20again%20(bubbling%20phase).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, as @EisaRezaei said in the first comment, using `e.stopPropagation()` in the form inside the portal, and submit type buttons, everything worked fine